# compare two array of string and store the result in another array

Tags: java

I want to compare two arrays and store the difference in another array

For example the two arrays might be

```
String[] a1 = { "cat" , "dog" };
String[] a2 = { "cat" , "rabbit" };
```

The resultant array would be like this

```
{ "rabbit" }
```

I use this code, but it does not work

```
int n = 0;
for (int k = 0; k <= temp.length; k++)
{
    for (int u = 0; u <= origenal.length; u++)
    {
        if (temp[k] != origenal[u] && origenal[u] != temp[k])
        {
            temp2[n] = temp[k];
            System.out.println(temp[u]);
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Easy: `String result = "rabbit";`

Comment: How did you only get "rabbit" in the result? We need much more information to help you.

Comment: @DanW I assume he is storing the difference between `a2` and `a1`: `a2\a1` is "rabbit".

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
String[] result = new String[100];
Int k = 0;
Boolean test = true;
for(i=0; i < a1.length; i++){
   for(j=0; j < a2.length; j++){
      if(a2[i].equals(a1[i])) continue;
      test = false
   }
   if(test == false) result[k++] = a1[i];
}
```

Comment: @user902383 duh, yes figured that out just after posting it

Answer (score 1):

I think that this may be what you are looking for. Note that it will only add to the third 'array' if the value exist in second array but not in first. In your example only rabbit will be stored, not dog (even though dog does not exist in both). This example could possibly be shortened but I wanted to keep it like this so it is easier to see what is going on.

First import:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Then do the following to populate and analyze the arrays

```
String a1[] = new String[]{"cat" , "dog"};    // Initialize array1
String a2[] = new String[]{"cat" , "rabbit"}; // Initialize array2

List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++)
{
    boolean foundString = false; // To be able to track if the string was found in both arrays
    for(int j = 0; j < a1.length; j++)
    {
        if(a1[j].equals(a2[i]))
        {
            foundString = true; 
            break; // If it exist in both arrays there is no need to look further
        }
    }
    if(!foundString) // If the same is not found in both..
        tempList.add(a2[i]); // .. add to temporary list
}
```

tempList will now contain 'rabbit' as according to the specification. If you necessary need it to be a third array you can convert it to that quite simply by doing the following:

```
String a3[] = tempList.toArray(new String[0]); // a3 will now contain rabbit
```

To print the content of either the List or Array do:

```
// Print the content of List tempList
for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(tempList.get(i));
}

// Print the content of Array a3
for(int i = 0; i < a3.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(a3[i]);
}
```

Comment: there are error in this statement for(String s2: a2), the error is "expected ; " is there any import should I do?

Comment: You should only need java.util.ArrayList and import java.util.List to use the list. I can reconstruct the loop to not use the for-each variant.

Comment: @user1888020 you can change from `for(String s2 : a2)` to `for(int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++)` and then in the boddy where you have `s2`, change it to `a2[i]`, same for s1 and a1, using another `int` variable like `j`.

Comment: I updated the example to not use the for-each style loop. Does that work better?

Comment: when I want to print the content of tempList, the error arise index 0, size 0,

Comment: How are you printing it? Is your code exactly as mine? Are you sure that you have stuff in array a1 and array a2?

Comment: I updated the code to show how you print stuff as well :) I've tested it on multiple machines and the code above works fine.

Comment: What Java version are you using and what is it that is not working with the code above?

Comment: jdk 1.7 , I think here is the error if (!foundString)// If the same is not found in both.. { //System.out.println(temp[i]); tempList.add(temp[i]); } because if I remove ! mark , which is mean foundString is true it work correctly

Comment: @user1888020 can you be more specific, what does not work? any error messages?

Comment: the tempList is empty, there are no element in it